# Keyboard shortcut for small git diff popup as seen when clicked on the gutter marker?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, goland

I sometimes want to see the diff of what has changed only per line, but I find it uncomfortable to always move your hand to the mouse and click on the gutter marker. Is there a way to assign a shortcut to open that little diff window (as seen in the image)? I couldn't find an IntelliJ action that opens it.

[image: small IntelliJ per line diff window]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That action is called [**Change Under Caret**](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85810#focus=Comments-27-916538.0-0).

By default, no shortcut is assigned to it. You can find it with [**Find Action**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/discover-intellij-idea.html#find-action) (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd> | <kbd>⇧⌘A</kbd>).

[image: Find Action - Change Under Caret]

You can also assign a shortcut to it right in this popup with <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> | <kbd>⌥⏎</kbd>.

---

Other useful shortcuts:

- Next Change: <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Down</kbd> | <kbd>⌃⌥⇧↓</kbd>
- Previous Change: <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Up</kbd> | <kbd>⌃⌥⇧↑</kbd>
- Rollback Lines: <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Z</kbd> | <kbd>⌥⌘Z</kbd>

Help documentation:

- [Review changes﻿ - Track changes to a file in the editor﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-changes-information.html#local_changes)
- [Source code navigation - Navigate between changes﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#navigate-between-changes)
- [Undo changes in Git repository﻿ - Revert uncommitted changes﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/undo-changes.html#revert-local-changes)

Answer (score 2):

Use the keyboard shortcuts for `Navigate:Navigate in File:Next Change/Previous Change`

To make it even easier, modify the shortcut for that command to your liking in `Preferences:Keymap`.